# Query mongo With joda.time.datetime using clojure-monger

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

I got this error code when tried query obj with `{$lte start $gte end}`, can u show me some sample of querying with coda.datetime?

```
IllegalArgumentException can't serialize class org.joda.time.DateTime org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField (BasicBSONEncoder.java:284)
```

The Func:

```
(defn data->orders [start end]
  (let [db (mg/get-db conn/mongo-db "db")
        coll "coll"
        formatter (f/formatter "YYYY-MM-dd")]
    (mc/find-maps db coll
                  {:created_at
                   {$gte (f/parse formatter start)
                    $lte (f/parse formatter end)}})))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/integration.html

Add to ns

```
(:require monger.joda-time)
```

See source:
https://github.com/michaelklishin/monger/blob/master/src/clojure/monger/joda_time.clj